# Android-speech-api + pocketsphinx android cause ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT

Tags: pocketsphinx-android, android-speech-api

After listening for a keyword (using pocketsphinx) i try to start the google speech recognizer but getting many calls of `onRmsChanged()` with negative 
numbers and than get the `ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT`.

Code:

```
PocketSphinxRecognizer.cancel();
GoogleSpeechRecognizer.startListening(SpeechRecognizerIntent);
```

I tried to run the line:

```
GoogleSpeechRecognizer.startListening(SpeechRecognizerIntent);
```

in `OnError()` if the error is `ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT` but got no response.

Edit:

```
10-01 05:45:33.165 1739-2055/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.net.ConnectivityManager$NetworkCallback', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.bc.ak.<init>
10-01 05:45:33.175 1739-2055/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.net.NetworkRequest$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.bc.ak.jh
10-01 05:45:33.235 1739-2055/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.AudioAttributes$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.c.a.<init>
10-01 05:45:33.260 1739-2055/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.AudioFormat$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.d.a.<init>
10-01 05:45:33.320 1739-2088/? E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.speech.service.START on com.google.android.gms
10-01 05:45:33.430 1739-2086/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.content.pm.LauncherApps', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.shared.multiuser.RemoteWorkDataClient.connect
10-01 05:45:33.650 1938-2108/? E/TinyUCM: modifier doesn't exists any more
10-01 05:45:33.995 2343-2667/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 6447
10-01 05:45:34.535 1739-2132/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.chromium.net.k', referenced from method org.chromium.net.NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect.<init>
10-01 05:45:37.280 25379-25379/? E/ctxmgr: [PlaceFenceHelper]NearbyBuffer is null!
10-01 05:45:39.160 1739-2191/? E/native: decoder_endpointer_stream.cc:23 Acoustic ep reader thread failed: *** Error status greco::STREAM_CANCELED: <no msg> ***
10-01 05:45:39.425 1938-2208/? E/AudioResampler: Unsupported sample format, 1 bits, 1 channels
10-01 05:45:39.450 1589-1589/com.example.manuel.lightbulb E/GoogleRecognitionListener: onError:6
```

Comment: Call PocketSphinxRecognizer.shutdown()

Comment: i have tried this but always get the same errors see my edit for the errors i have also tried all the variations on stop(),cancel(),shutdown()

Comment: Maybe it needs some timeout. Android recording implementation is not always perfect.

Comment: i was able to ignore this error in the end by handling it in the onError() method